# How can I check if an edit cell in javafx tableview is correct, and if it isn't: how can I set the cell value back?

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx

I made an editable table with `TableView` in JavaFX. Now I want to check if the input is correct. If it's wrong I want to reset the cell's value to the old value.
Like I edit a "55" in the cell to a "160". I want that after I press <kbd>Enter</kbd>, the "160" dissapears. I made it like this:

```
public void handle(CellEditEvent event) {
    if (groups_list.get(table_persona.getSelectionModel().getSelectedIndex()).getAge() > 100) {
        Number a = (Number) event.getNewValue();
        ((Persona) event.getTableView().getItems().get(
            event.getTablePosition().getRow()
        )).setAge(a.intValue());
    } else {
        Number a = groups_list.get(table_persona.getSelectionModel().getSelectedIndex()).getAge();
        ((Persona) event.getTableView().getItems().get(
            event.getTablePosition().getRow()
        )).setAge(a.intValue());
        error_message_group.textProperty().set("to old");
    }
    table_groups.setItems(persona_list);
}
```

but it doesn't work. The "160" is still there. Only if I click again in the cell, the "55" reappears.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the problem. And
unrelated to your problem: please learn java naming conventions and stick to them

Answer (score 0):

The answer is the method refresh():

```
    public void handle(CellEditEvent event) {
        if (groups_list.get(table_persona.getSelectionModel().getSelectedIndex()).getAge() > 100) {
            Number a = (Number) event.getNewValue();
            ((Persona) event.getTableView().getItems().get(
                event.getTablePosition().getRow()
            )).setAge(a.intValue());
        } else {
       error_message_group.textProperty().set("to old");
       table_group.refresh();
        }
    }
```

Comment: no - most probably not: if refresh seems to be the answer your setup is wrong ... with a probability very near to 1

Comment: ookay .. I was wrong: this is one of the rare corner cases where refresh is fine to workaround a bug: bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8187314